# Get video creation time with millisecond precision for Android and ios

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to extract video creation time for both Android and ios devices. I need the timestamp with millisecond precision.
For Android, I used 'MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE"
For ios, I used NSDate 'NSFileCreationDate'

In both cases, I am getting timestamp only till seconds precision.

Is there a way I can get the timestamp with milliseconds precision?

Comment: How do you format this date ? MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE. I assume you may have given correct formatting

Comment: 20181125T135149.000Z is the format I am getting the date in Android and ios is NSFileCreationDate = "2021-01-18 13:29:11 +0000";

Comment: I guess you can't get that as Date object doesn't return. You can see here relevant information is year, month , day, hour, minutes, seconds etc but not millisecond. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Is there any other way to capture milliseconds? Not sure if any other library can provide that